# Webpack: Using external to inject requirement

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel Mix and Webpack to compile SPAs from a base framework and an instance structure.

(All code below is abbreviated for readability.)

I use `vue-route-generator` to build a router from the table:

```
const routes = require('vue-route-generator')
.generateRoutes({
    '~', // Path to directory of page components.
    importPrefix: pages+'/', // String to add to importing component path.
    dynamicImport: true, // Use dynamic import expression (`import()`) to import component.
    nested: false, // DO NOT always treat generated route path as nested.
});
```

`vue-route-generator` produces the code that I expect:

```
function Index() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "index" */ '~/index.vue')
}
function People() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "people" */ '~/people.vue')
}
export default [...]
```

I defined an external so that I can inject my route as a `require`ment into the framework.

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        ...
        externals: [
            { routes, ... }
        ]
    };
});
```

The injection occurs as I expect... almost. When I inspect the injected code in devtools, I see this:

```
/***/ "routes":
/*!*!*\
  !*** external "Index() {\n  return import(\n    /* webpackChunkName: \"index\" *_/ '~/index.vue'\n  )\n}\nfunction People() {\n  return import(\n    /* webpackChunkName: \"people\" *_/ '~/people.vue'\n  )\n}\n\nexport default [\n  {\n    name: 'index',\n    path: '/',\n    component: Index\n  },\n  {\n    name: 'people',\n    path: '/people',\n    component: People\n  }\n]\n" ***!
  \***/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = Index() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "index" */ '~/index.vue')
}
function People() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "people" */ '~/people.vue')
}
export default [...]
```

Obviously it should be this:

```
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
function Index() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "index" */ '~/index.vue')
}
function People() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "people" */ '~/people.vue')
}
module.exports = [...]
```

What do I need to do so that Webpack will inject the routing code correctly?